# Todays strategy to keep git submodule checkouts in sync with commit-IDs?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull, git-checkout, git-config

A lot of questions about automatically update submodules have been asked on 
StackOverflow including:

- [Is there a way to make git pull automatically update submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611512)
- [Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169)
- [Why doesn't `git checkout` automatically do `git submodule update --recursive`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328053)

But it looks to me as for git submodules there is no single approach yet which works like `svn up` regarding svn-externals.

So since git is changing every day I dare to ask again:

**Is there a (convenient) way to *init* and *automatically update* submodule checkouts (i.e. keep in sync with their corresponding submodule commit IDs) for `checkout` *and* `pull` (i.e. `merge` and `rebase`)?**

Currently I have two approaches for this:

**#1: create a `post-checkout`, `post-merge` and `post-rewrite` hook with the following content**

```
#!/bin/sh
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

as you can already see this approach has several disadvantages:

- it's **complicated** and probably needs a script to make it working reliably
- does not work well if you **use these git-hooks already**
- the commit hooks are only active **on this clone** (has to be re-done by
  everyone working on this project on every single clone)
- setup is **non-standard** and will confuse others

**#2: configure aliases for `pull` and `checkout`**

```
git config --global alias.up 'pull --recurse-submodules'
git config --global alias.co 'checkout --recurse-submodules'
```

But this isn't nice neither:

- it won't `--init` the submodules (can be solved by running `pull`/`checkout` and `submodule update` separately instead
- it's **non-standard** and won't work with scripts and snippets
- it's **easy to forget to use** `up`/`co` instead of `pull`/`checkout`
- it works **only on the local** machine/user

This approach would be a bit more like I want it to be if you could do something
like

```
git config --global pull.recurseSubmodules true
git config --global pull.initSubmodules true
git config --global checkout.recurseSubmodules true
git config --global checkout.initSubmodules true
```

.. but you can't, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Since [Git 2.13](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt#L145), you can do `git checkout --recurse-submodules <ref>` which will make sure that the working tree(s) of active submodule(s) are in sync with the submodule commit(s) recorded in the superproject at `<ref>`.

Since [Git 2.14](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.14.0.txt#L117), you can do `git pull --recurse-submodules`, which will do a normal pull and will then invoke `git submodule update --init --recursive` (with `--rebase` if you pulled with `--rebase`), keeping active submodule(s) working tree(s) in sync with the submodule commit(s) recorded in the superproject.

Since [Git 2.15](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt#L358), setting `git config submodule.recurse true` will make this the default behaviour for [all commands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse) that accept the `--recurse-submodules` flag, except `clone` and `ls-files`.

There is no way to make this behaviour the default *without* changing your configuration or using these options.

---

Note that doing `git checkout --recurse-submodules <branch>` when the current branch has no submodules and `<branch>` has initialized nested submodules fails before [Git 2.27](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88/Documentation/RelNotes/2.27.0.txt#L181).