# PyPI automatic deployment

Tags: python, git, github, package-managers, pypi

I have a [repository](https://github.com/coala-analyzer/coala-bears) (on GitHub) consisting of a number of modules that can be added to the main [project](https://github.com/coala-analyzer/coala) as plugins. I want to set up the repository such that an automatic PyPI deployment is triggered (only for the changed module) every time a pull request is accepted.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Travis-CI supports automatic PyPI deployments but for the entire repository. I need it only for a folder inside the repo (a module).

Comment: Have you looked into [git submodules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611512/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-pull-automatically-update-submodules) or [git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/)?

Comment: @gaborous To use git submodules or git subtree I'll have to keep each module into its own git repository. I want to keep all modules in one repository. All issues go to the same repo as well as all PR.

Comment: no, not with git subtree, your modules will stay on the same repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `after_success:` option to implement [custom deployments on travis-ci](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/).

Something like:

```
after_success:
    "cd $subfolder && python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi"
```

You will have to provide your pypi credentials yourself using whichever method you find best.

Comment: I want to trigger the deployment after the PR has been merged to the master. If I used your command Travis would deploy it every time a PR is received.

Comment: You can use `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` and `TRAVIS_BRANCH` to determine if it is a merge into master. The first should be the string value `false` and the second should be `master`.

Comment: @Ibrahim here is a list of all environment variables you can use to determine if it is the right branch / etc to perform a pypi update https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and report back.