# Git auto patch submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-patch

I have a C++ project with a submodule (which I have only read permission).
Early it was just a copy of code instead of submodule. And during the work this copy has been changed a bit.
So, how can I make a auto applying these changes after each submodule update?

It's really small changes, but removing them makes me to grand code editing.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611512/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-pull-automatically-update-submodules) helps you

Comment: @ThiruShetty no, it's reverse problem. I have unpushed commit in submodule, and I want to automatically rebase it to every submodule commit. Also this unpushed commit must be stored in father repository to share those changes.