# Does git submodule update --recursive override fetchRecurseSubmodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule who's submodules I don't need. For example:

```
mainProject
  - usefulSubmodule
    - notNeededSubmodule
```

So in `mainProject`, I define my `.gitmodules` like so:

```
[submodule "usefulSubmodule"]
    path = lib/usefulSubmodule
    url = https://whatever
    fetchRecurseSubmodules = false
```

Then I run `git submodule update --init --recursive` after updating, and it seems that this is ignoring the value of `fetchRecurseSubmodules` (which I guess may be true according to the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#Documentation/gitmodules.txt-submoduleltnamegtfetchRecurseSubmodules )

So therefore my question is, how do I disable this behavior without overriding it during update? What is the best way to update all my submodules while respecting that flag?

Comment: ... run `git submodule update init` without `--recursive`? (Presumably you'll then need to set `fetchRecurseSubmodules = true` in any submodules where you *do* want the recursion.)

Comment: Exactly. The docs do point out that a nonspecific update updates all the .gitmodules submodules, you've simply imagined the need for that option here.

Comment: ah perhaps I'm missing something. So is `on-demand` the default for this property if it is not present?

Comment: There's a lot of [new knobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69322941/5994170) since 2.34.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is `on-demand` the default for this property if it is not present?

Yes, that is what [`git config fetch.recurseSubmodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-fetchrecurseSubmodules) specifies:

> When set to `on-demand` (the default value), `fetch` and `pull` will only recurse into a populated submodule when its superproject retrieves a commit that updates the submodule’s reference.

Note: if you want to override locally (for just one command) a configuration:

```
git -c fetch.recurseSubmodules=on-demand submodule update --init
```

But in this case, it is not needed (this is just to illustrate how one can set a config for one `git` command)