# Git pull not downloading contents of submodule even with submodule.recurse set

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I execute `git pull`, I want all the submodules to download.  According to the winning answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4611512) question, setting `git config --global submodule.recurse true` will change the behavior of `git pull` so that it recurses through the submodules.  That is not happening for some reason.

Specifically, I have a repo with a submodule called `alib`.  So I get it into a fresh location.

```
git config --global submodule.recurse true

mkdir foo
cd foo
git clone https://something.com/MyRepoWithSubmodule.git
git pull
```

The `alib` directory is there, however, none of the contents of the submodule are.
What am I missing in order to get the contents of `alib` to download during `git pull`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (`git-config(1)`) says about `submodule.recurse`
(emphasis mine):

> `submodule.recurse`
>
> A boolean indicating if commands should enable the `--recurse-submodules` option by default. Applies to all commands that support this option (`checkout`, `fetch`, `grep`, `pull`, `push`, `read-tree`, `reset`, `restore` and `switch`) **except `clone` and `ls-files`**...

So, the `submodule.recurse` option explicitly does not apply to `git clone`. You need to either `git clone --recurse-submodules`, or after cloning run `git submodule update --init --recursive`.

Running `git pull` immediately after `git clone` is effectively a no-op (unless someone happens to push something immediately after the `clone` operation, there won't be any changes to pull).

---

With `submodule.recurse` set to `true`, running `git pull` will automatically update submodules that have a new commit in the parent repo:

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), 278 bytes | 278.00 KiB/s, done.
From localhost:/home/lars/tmp/demo/repo3
   c07f940..044186f  main       -> origin/main
Fetching submodule repo1
From localhost:/home/lars/tmp/demo/repo1
   cf4468f..da359ec  main       -> origin/main
Fetching submodule repo2
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Updating c07f940..044186f
Fast-forward
 repo1 | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.
Submodule path 'repo1': rebased into 'da359ec652e59cbd3cbc23ea405cc106519344a8'
```

See the `Fetching submodule ...` in response to the `git pull`.

Comment: Understood, but let's say someone makes a change in the submodule, I'd like to get those changes when I run `git pull`.

Comment: That should work if you have already initialized submodules via `clone` or `submodules init` (and if `git pull` results in new commits that makes changes to submodule versions).

Comment: I tried the following: `git clone --recurse-submodules repoUrl`, then `git submodule update --init --recursive`.  And it did download everything.  Then I went into the repo of the submodule and added a file.  I tried to do `git pull` and even though it said `fetching submodule alib`, the added file didn't appear.  I then went into the `alib` subdirectory (e.g. the submodule) and executed `git pull` - failed because it needed to have <remote> <branch>, so I ran `git pull origin master` and then it did get the latest file.  So it doesn't recurse.  You have to do it manually.

Comment: And what's worse, if I am working in submodule's subdirectory, I can't push back to the submodule repo because the HEAD has been detached when creating the submodule dependency in the first place.

Comment: Well, that last bit is just how submodules work. You will be happiest if you treat submodules as read-only.

Comment: W/r/t  your earlier comment, see my update to the answer.