# Can different branches each have their own URL for submodules and still easily switch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in git, and I want to be able to have different branches have different URLs for this submodule, specified in .gitmodules. I know that's *possible*, but whenever I switch between these branches now it's a whole process to get the submodule onto the right hash. I have to deinit the submodule, delete the modules pathway under .git/, and then reinit, which takes a while. Is there an easier way to switch branches and get on the right hash, considering each branch uses a different submodule URL?

Comment: Use `post-checkout` hook. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37383406/7976758 and https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils/blob/973696c7e556d6a67ef890e159dbd0290233a820/submodule-hooks/post-merge-checkout

Comment: Another solution — don't switch branches. Instead have a separate clone for each branch with that branch checked out. Please let me remind that `git worktree` doesn't work with submodules, you need a full clone for every branch.

Answer (score 2):

Branches—by which I mean branch *names*—are not relevant here.<sup>1</sup>  What matters are the *commits* ... and, unfortunately in your own case, the *specific patterns with which you check out each commit*.

A submodule is nothing more or less than a separate Git repository.  If you don't have the submodule *yet*, Git has to run `git clone` to get it, and Git finds the instructions *for* that `git clone` command by combining the information in some specific commit in the form of a *gitlink*—a path like `path/to/submodule` whose entry is `mode 160000`, i.e., a gitlink, with some hash ID—plus information in that same commit in a file named `.gitmodules`.

Let's take an illustration for example.  Suppose the super-repository is named `super`, and in commit `a123456`, `path/to/sub` has mode 160000 and says `commit 5555555`.  You clone the superproject and check out commit `a123456`.  The submodule is not yet cloned, but the index for the superproject says "we need commit `5555555` for `path/to/sub`" at this point.

If you now run `git submodule update --init` (or have used recursive clone which does this for you), Git now notices that, hey, the repository isn't cloned yet, so it looks in `.gitmodules` for `path/to/sub` to find the instructions for cloning it.  It then runs `git clone` with (in effect) `--no-checkout`, then enters the submodule and checks out commit `5555555` (by raw hash ID).

But now `path/to/sub` is associated with a submodule that *is* cloned.  Let's say you now check out commit `b789abc` in `super` and *it* says "use commit `5678567`".  That goes into Git's index (for `super`: the submodule `sub` index and working tree are as yet untouched).  If you now run `git submodule update`, or have turned on recursive checkout (which does this for you), Git notices that the submodule is already cloned, and **does not bother to look in the `.gitmodules` file from `b789abc`**.

Note that, had you not run `git submodule update --init` while on commit `a123456`, the submodule would not yet be cloned.  So actions in `super` would now look at the `.gitmodules` file as it appears in commit `b789abc`, which might have a completely different URL.  Git would then clone *that* URL and look for commit `5678567` there.

This is the problem you're trying to work around.  There isn't a workaround for it, other than the horrible manual process you have been using.

(The usual term for this problem is that you have a ["path-dependent outcome"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence).  Git doesn't expect this and just doesn't handle it properly.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, multiple branch names can point to the *same commit*.  If `main` and `develop` both point to commit `a123456`, it won't matter which *name* you use, as you get commit `a123456` either way.  Branch names *move over time*, so just because `main` identifies `a123456` today does not mean it will identify `a123456` tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a different submodule *name* for each of the different source URLs.

For example, assume that I sometimes want to use package `pkg` from source `url_a`, and sometimes use `pkg` acquired from source `url_b`. I would first create two *independent* submodules `pkg_from_a` and `pkg_from_b` in my repository:

```
git submodule add <url_a> pkg_from_a
git submodule add <url_b> pkg_from_b
```

Now I have two independent submodules, but how do I select the one in use? That is done by creating a symbolic link `pkg` which points to either `pkg_from_a` or `pkg_from_b` as required. For instance, if I start from a branch which should use `pkg_from_a`, I would create and commit the link like this:

```
ln -s pkg_from_a pkg     # NOTE: Unix syntax for creating a symbolic link
git add pkg
git commit pkg
```

Modifying the link is all that would be necessary to switch between the two submodules. The link can change on a commit-by-commit basis, so different branches can easily use `pkg` sourced from different locations.