# How can I check out a branch that manages a path with a submodule when the current branch does not?

Tags: git

I created a branch in which I converted a path in my repository to a submodule. I haven't merged that work into `master` yet. Having finished converting that path to a submodule, I attempted to switch back to `master` and got the following error:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> [ ... a list of files that are now being managed by a submodule ...]

Makes sense. So, I did `git checkout --force master`. Then, when I switched back to the branch that tracks the path with a submodule, that path was empty except for the `.git` pointer find that you find in submodules. To get the submodule re-checked out to the commit designated in the index, I need to do `git submodule update --force`.

Is there a simpler way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep a directory:

- as a submodule in one branch
- as a set of managed files in `master`

You will have the kind of experience you saw, since [`git submodule update` isn't automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1899792/6309).

One workaround would be to maintain two clones (one on master, one on your branch).

The other would be to setup a [`post-checkout` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post-checkout) which would:

- detect the checked out branch
- do the `git submodule update --force` is appropriate.

Something along the [lines of that hook](https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils/blob/master/submodule-hooks/post-merge-checkout) (or [this one](http://lists-archives.com/git/702765-implement-sample-post-checkout-hook-to-checkout-new-unchanged-submodules.html)).

Comment: Great suggestion. That's definitely something I can do. Thank you.