# Get branche names of git submodules in another directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have checked out a project that includes some submodules.

First I checked out my `project` and then the `submodules`:

```
git clone git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/project.git
```

Initiatiated the submodules for that `branch` with the latest:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then I checked out the specific branch that includes the submodules. I just want to get the **branch** name of each sumbodule.

**But**:

```
$ git --git-dir path/to/my/submodule rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
fatal: not a git repository: 'path/to/my/submodule'


$ cd  path/to/my/submodule 
$ (detached*)$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 24bbc55)
  develop
```

Why the first command shows that it is not a git submodule? (while it is)
The checkout is done from a specific branch ('develop') of the submodule. How can I get the actual branch name (and not the git `sha`?)

Answer (score 0):

From your project list the branch name and status of each submodule in your git repository:

```
git submodule foreach 'git status'
```

From your submodule list the branch name of that submodule

```
git branch
```

The reason for the detached state of git submodules can be found in another question that has been made here: stackoverflow.com/a/48556186/3564632

Comment: thanks that seems to be working; any idea however why my submodules are in `detached` state?

Comment: You can find an answer here about the default detached state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48556186/3564632