# What does "HEAD detached from 77f2f45" mean?

Tags: git, git-submodules

This is an output of `git-branch -av` inside a submodule directory (which points to *a branch* of another repository):

```
# git branch -av
* (HEAD detached from 77f2f45)               29364b9 Merge branch 'adt' into v3
```

What is the current revision of this submodule, 77f2f45 or 29364b9?

Edit: This is obviously not a duplicate of [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master). The output `HEAD detached from` doesn't even appear in that question.

This question isn't asking what a detached head is or why the head is detached (it's a submodule after all), but what the output `from 77f2f45` means. An answer should probably start with "77f2f45 is the commit ...".

Comment: It's normal for a submodule to be in a detached head state, since a submodule is always tracking a certain commit. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48556186/7598462).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Answer (score 0):

77f2f45 is the commit that the submodules HEAD is pointing too.
If this was a submodule and I did `checkout 77f2f45` and this commit was not the most recent, I would be in a detached state, which means any changes I commit, will not be part of a branch.  HOWEVER, the default state of submodule is a detached state if you havn't explicitly told it to track a branch, even if you checked out the most recent commit of said branch. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36375256/11308441 for more detail on this.

29364b9 is the commit that the parent repo is currently using to reference your submodule.