# git submodule reference not show current branch, but show commit hash

Tags: git, git-submodules

This is my submodules

`+a3ebd2c9635f67ef7d0b430e505e40fa65f3abd4 android-libs-core (0.3-145-ga3ebd2c)
 6041beecf8082b2e68b597e3305c8b9ef4012772 android-libs-debug (heads/master)
 df7dad74c8b922714b2f17defb8172df7ecf32ea android-libs-router (v1.1-5-gdf7dad7)
 7a669bac24430841a5d86c0d90964cd612005769 android_libs_view (heads/master)`

PS: Even not show current branch, the sub module also tracking the master branch , so I have my doubts. see the submodule information.

`+a3ebd2c9635f67ef7d0b430e505e40fa65f3abd4 android-libs-core (0.3-145-ga3ebd2c)`

**(0.3-145-ga3ebd2c) mean's what and is it right ?**

normal case will show the submodule's current branch, so I am worried of my git repertory has some problem

Comment: Don't post images of text. It's much easier to copy-paste the text as text and, if appropriate, format it as code using the `{}` button on the question editor toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by noting that a submodule *is* a Git repository in its own right.  As a repository, it has everything a repository has: commits, branch names, tag names, an index, a work-tree, and so on.  At the same time, it's a *sub*module, surrounded in some way by another repository.

Git probably should have direct support for "subrepos".<sup>1</sup>  It doesn't.  *Subrepos* is a term I made up here to tell these (unspecified) things apart from Git's *submodules*.  I am not the first to make up this term; searching for "subrepos" will find several actual implementations (all different).

## Submodules are designed to be detached

Git thinks of<sup>1</sup> submodules as external dependencies: something outside your project and outside your control.  In your project—which Git now calls the *superproject*, to distinguish it from the *submodule* Git repository—you will record:

- The URL for the repository to clone: the argument you would give to `git clone`.
- The place in your superproject where the clone should go.

These two items go into a file named `.gitmodules` in the top of your repository.  In case you want more than one submodule, each one has a name:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "path/to/sub1"]
        path = path/to/sub1
        url = ssh://one.example.com/repo1.git

[submodule "path2/sub2"]
        path = path2/sub2
        url = ssh://two.example.com/repo2.git
```

The `path` is somewhat redundant since the submodule's name is the path name, but that's how these are laid out.  In any case, Git will, in effect, make an empty directory at the `path`, `cd` there, and `git clone` the URL into that initially-empty directory.<sup>2</sup>

There is something missing here.  When you clone a repository, you also `git checkout` some *particular commit*, typically by a branch name like `master`.  You do this so that the *work-tree* for that repository is populated with files from that commit.  (Git actually copies the files to the *index* for that work-tree first, but the index entries are tiny, and if you never do any *work* in the sub-repository, you won't care about this.)

So: what *commit* should Git check out, in the work-tree for this other repository?

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers—they hate that!

<sup>2</sup>In older versions of Git, Git literally does that, and the sub-module repository is quite indistinguishable from any other repository.  That method still works, but modern Git now puts the `.git` directory for the submodule inside the `.git` directory for the superproject.  Instead of a `.git` directory, it writes a `.git` file that contains the *path* of the submodule's `.git` container.  This makes it possible to discover, from the submodule, that the submodule is in fact a submodule *as well as* an independent Git repository.

#### Names of commits

Git has many ways to name a commit.  For a complete list, see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  You can always translate any of these names to a raw commit hash ID.  In fact, the `git rev-parse` command is designed to do just that:<sup>3</sup>

```
$ git rev-parse master
0afbf6caa5b16dcfa3074982e5b48e27d452dbbb
```

We already noted above that `git clone` ends with a `git checkout`, usually of a *branch name* like `master`.  However, you can run `git clone -b tag-name`, where `git clone` runs `git checkout tag-name`.  If you do this, you will find that you are in "detached HEAD" mode.

If you run `git clone --no-checkout`, the clone step *doesn't* run `git checkout` at all, and now you can use `git checkout hash-id` to check out a specific commit.  Once again, you will be in "detached HEAD" mode.

Hence, using a name to check out one specific commit is, with one important difference, basically *the same as* using `git checkout hash-id` to check out the commit to which the name points—the hash ID you would get from using `git rev-parse` on the name.

The one important difference is, of course, that *if* the name is a *branch name* like `master`, Git will put you "on the branch", rather than in "detached HEAD" mode.  (You can force detached HEAD mode anyway using `git checkout --detach name`, if you want.)

The important thing to note about these many names for a commit is that **in the end, the names just translate to a hash ID.**  It's the hash ID, not the name, that *truly* identfies *that particular commit*.  In fact, the point of a *branch* name—as opposed to, say, a tag name<sup>4</sup>—is that the branch name *changes* over time: it may point to `0afbf6caa...` today, but to `468165c1d...` tomorrow.

So a submodule is a Git repository that we *don't* control, for (say) a library of various functions.  Suppose our superproject *uses* that library, and works with *one particular version* of that library: `v1.1` which is `a123456...`.  What we want to record, then is:

- the URL of the repository;
- the path where the repository is to be checked out; and
- `v1.1` or `a123456...`: the *specific hash ID to check out*, as a detached HEAD.

This way, when we `git checkout master` in the superproject, whatever our `master` hash ID turns out to be, we want Git to `git clone` the subproject if necessary and then check out **the one specific commit `a123456...`**.  This will be a detached HEAD in the submodule!

Over time, we will work on our own superproject.  We may need a new feature from `v1.2` of the library, which is commit `b789abc...` rather than `a123456...`.  So we'll go into the submodule, `git checkout v1.2` to get a *new* detached HEAD commit, go back into our superproject, make everything work with the updated submodule, and then `git add` (to the index for the work-tree for the superproject) a record saying *use `b789abc...`*.  We will then `git commit` to save the new pairing: **the new commit uses `b789abc...`**.

It doesn't matter how we got `b789abc...` checked out in the submodule.  What matters is that the superproject now *works with* that commit.  We want *superproject* commits from here on to say *use that specific commit from the submodule.*

---

<sup>3</sup>The `rev-parse` command can do a lot more than just turn a name into a hash ID, but that's one of its main functions.

<sup>4</sup>Tag names, unlike branch names, are not supposed to change.  Tag names also have the advantage of being something *we* choose: `v2.17.0` is probably more meaningful than `468165c1d...`.  It might be nice if Git submodules could be specified by tag names, but they can't (at least today).

---

#### Conclusion (or is it?)

Specific commits are detached HEADs.  Superprojects use specific commits out of their submodules.  Therefore, superprojects call for detached HEADs in submodules.  That's it—that's *why* Git is designed to work this way.

The main thing that this *doesn't* address is the updating process.  We mentioned above that at some point, we want to update the freeze-point within the submodule.  To do that, we will `cd` into the submodule work-tree and start doing Gitty things like `git checkout branchname`, maybe with a `git fetch` first.  **At this point** names—branch and/or tag names—may become important.  It might be nice to record them in the superproject somewhere.

That's what adding `branch = name` to a superproject's `.gitmodules` entry for a submodule does.  Newer versions of Git have some support for this: in particular, `git submodule update` can (depending on options) use it.  The [documentation for this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) is rather difficult to read.  It helps a lot to keep in mind that each submodule Git repository *is* a Git repository all on its own, as well as being a submodule.  Since it *is* a repository, it can have its own `origin` remote as well as its own branches, so that running `git fetch` updates `origin/master`, and so on.

As far as the superproject's Git is concerned, though, the submodule actually has *one specific commit checked out*.  This is true whether or not the submodule Git is in "detached HEAD" mode.  The commits you make in the superproject record one specific hash ID, every time you make a commit.  That one hash ID is the one stored in the index for the work-tree for the superproject.  ("The one stored in the index for the work-tree for the superproject" is kind of a mouthful, and worse, some of the usual tools for inspecting the index, of which there are not that many, don't really work very well for submodules.)

Comment: My question is not detached, use git submodule command, some submodule 's reference show the last commit hash and some submodule 's reference show the current branch. so, I want all of submodule's reference show the current branch

Comment: The status is correct. *It doesn't matter whether the submodule is on a branch.* The output is from `git describe` so it is relative to a *tag*. Unless you intend to `cd` into the submodule and begin working—in which case, just *do* that—it doesn't matter if the submodule is on a branch or not; what matters is the *checked-out commit*.

Comment: I see, thank U very much!  I `cd` into submodule and the branch is on master,  thank U again!

Comment: Cit. "It might be nice to record them in the superproject somewhere.". "It might be nice" is not the same as "it has to be" , nevertheless Git forces me in superproject to do commit reflecting the fact there was an update in submodule.  If "it might be nice" applies I should have the choice to record it in superproject or not, however Git doesn't provide me with choice.

Comment: Cit. "That's what adding branch = name to a superproject's .gitmodules entry for a submodule does." - Isn't it that way .gitmodules is effective only while submodule is being initialized (either in separate step or in superproject's recursive clone)? Shouldn't branch = name be made in repo's config instead? Isn't it that way a working repository (such one been established in past) takes all submodule's config from '.git' or command line and never from '.gitmodules'. '.gitmodules' seems to be template for repo config.

Comment: Cit.: "So a submodule is a Git repository that we don't control, for (say) a library of various functions." one might like to contribute to sub-project at the same time they contributes to superproject - it is one of use-cases submodules address.. See also first paragraph of https://github.com/progit/progit2/blob/master/book/07-git-tools/sections/submodules.asc#working-on-a-submodule

Comment: @Na13-c: I'm referring here to the general background design principles that went into making submodules. Yes, you *can* use them in a case where you *do* control both repositories. But that use-case is a subset of the *design* case. Analogies are imperfect, but consider designing a tow truck. One option is to design a tow truck that can only tow cars *you* build. Another is to design a truck that can tow *any* car. Does the latter work to tow cars that you build?

Comment: Cit.: "It doesn't matter how we got b789abc... checked out in the submodule". Actually myself wonders why someone would need to get b789abc... checked out in the submodule. Isn't it that way this commit was made in superproject? Please notice submodule and superprojects are two different repositories as cit.: "So a submodule is a Git repository that we don't control, for (say) a library of various functions.". Why should I need one commit from superproject to have in submodule? Isn't it that way superproject depends on submodule but usually there is no reverse-dependency for these two?

Comment: @torek Thanks for feedback from you. Kindly consider question raised and your friendly answer discuss quite concrete problems (situation or use-case specific). For reader it might be annoying to point to generic questions without giving a hint the information is of generic nature - reader can get problems on matching information provided in that region to specific questions in origin.

Comment: Yes, there is no linkage going back from the submodule to the superproject at all. This is the source of numerous issues with submodules: in particular, if a superproject depends on some specific commit *C* within a submodule, and whoever controls the submodule repository does a history rewrite that discards commit *C*, the superproject is no longer capable of obtaining commit *C*, yet still refers to it by hash ID.

Comment: There is no way to fix this in the submodule design. Note that using a submodule branch name is not a fix: whoever controls the submodule could, in addition to doing a history rewrite, alter the branch names.