# Why is my GIT Submodule *NOT* a detached head?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-detached-head

Basically the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master).

I'm cloning a repo that has a submodule in it. After running

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

when I `cd` to the subdirectory that contains the submodule, I expect to see that I am in a detached HEAD state when I do `git status` but I'm not. I read up on submodules and I see you *can* setup tracking for a submodule but I have never done those steps.

I've reproduced this behavior with fresh clones of the repo in different directories; it's as if the submodules are being setup to be tracked right away somehow. My co-worker running on the same machine, same version of git, same .gitconfig (except usernames) gets the expected behavior (detached HEAD in submodule directory) with the same repository.

[image: Screencap of clone and submodule initialization/update]

Comment: It's hard to read the screenshot, but it looks to me like you're in a *different* directory named `common`, not in the *submodule* directory named `common`. An easy way to be sure is to use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` which will tell you where the work-tree lives: if it's the main repo work-tree, you're still in the main repo; if it's the submodule repo, you're in the submodule.

Comment: Yep, you're right, two directories with the same name

Answer (score 0):

@torkek is correct, my coincidence the submodule was in a *different* subdirectory also named common >.<