# Git submdule - Change Banch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I have a question regarding submodules in git:

I have a repository "SuperRepo" with submodule "A". Submodule "A" points to branch "develop" in .gitmodules.
If I create a new branch in "SuperRepo", let's assume "fancyFeature", I sometimes change the branch of submodule "A" to a new branch with the same name. This is not always the case, but sometimes.

I can submit this change and the submodule points to a commit on branch "fancyFeature". But since .gitmodules still points to develop, I always have unattached heads (at least that's my explanation). Is there any way to change the branch of a subrepo without having a detached head?

Thanks for your help!

P.S.:If I change the .gitmodules to "fancyFeature", I do not get detached heads. That's where my conclusion comes from...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+head

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the linked answers refer to repos without the change in subrepo branches. I do not have detached heads, if I stay on the same branch in my submodules. The tracking information is not updated, if I checkout a new branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git submodules are using detached HEADs by default and there is no direct support to change this.

But you can:

- set `submodule.XXX.branch` (in `.gitmodules) to the branch
- go to the HEAD of this branch with

  ```
  git submodule update
  ```

  This command implies `--checkout` by default.
- create the branch manually and use

  ```
  git submodule update --rebase
  git submodule update --merge
  ```

  This will keep your branch.

You can override the default update method by setting `submodule.XXX.update` to `rebase`, `merge` or `checkout`.

You can add `--remote` to fetch the submodule branch and merge/rebase/checkout this commit.

To create branches you can iterate through submodules like

```
git submodule foreach 'git -B feature-branch || :`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My current workaround is to change the .gitmodules and run:
`#!/bin/sh

set -e

git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
    while read path_key path
    do
        url_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.url/')
        url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$url_key")
        git submodule add $url $path
    done`