# git - submodule - checkout banch instead of hashes

Tags: git, git-submodules

i have a git repo with multiple submodules.

when checking out, i usually do as follows

```
git clone URL # without --recursive!
```

so i have a single main repository, checked out in master

```
git checkout mybranchname_main_repo
```

now i have a single main repository checked out in its branch

```
git submodule update --init # now i checkout submodules because now they point to their supposed branch hash and not the master
```

now have the main repository in its branch, with its submodules (repos) checkout out to the last commited hash which is typically also in a development branch and not master

the issue im having is that all submodules checkout the last commited hash value and not the branch/head.

is there a command that i can add an additional command making the submodules checkout the branch from their hash value in HEAD?

something like: (warning, this is pseudo code)

git submodule foreach checkout HEAD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+head

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `branch = <branchname>` directly into `.gitmodules` will allow `git submodule update --remote` to (effectively) update to the branch. You can also add this information with `git submodule add -b`.

Alternatively, `git submodule foreach` exists, and executes an arbitrary shell command in each submodule. Therefore, `git submodule foreach 'git checkout HEAD'` is also a perfectly valid command to check every submodule out to `HEAD`.

Alternatively: [Check this question which goes into a lot more detail with plenty of options.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)