# Git submodule updating - HEAD doesn't match up to git log

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-commit

I'm having trouble getting git's submodules to update properly when I pull a repository and the submodule's commit has changed.  First off, I believe this question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master) question because that question is concerned with staying up to date with a particular branch.  I don't want the latest commit on a branch, I want the commit specified in the parent repository.

#### Here's my scenario:

Git repo `A` has repo `B` as a submodule.  Repo `A` lists submodule `B` as being on commit `abc`.

Then, inside repo `A`, I do a `git pull` and receive a new commit for repo `A`.  This new commit states that submodule `B` should now be on commit `def`.  I run a `git submodule update` just to make sure everything is up to date.

#### Now here's where the problem arises.

I `cd` into submodule `B` and run `git status`.  It reports `HEAD detached at abc`.  Hmm, that's not right, it should be on `def`.  **But here's the confusing part** - I run `git log` and the very first commit it lists is `def`, preceded by `abc`!  **How can that be?** Shouldn't `git log` always start with `HEAD`?  And if it knows about the new commit, **why hasn't the working copy updated to reflect that?**

Even after getting the submodule in the state described above, I can't figure out what `git submodule ...` command, if any, would move the `B`'s head to be at `def`.  The only fix I found was to `cd` into `B` and manually run `git checkout def`.

Help, please!  I want a `git pull` in repo `A` to update submodule `B` to the commit has as indicated by `A`.

Comment: You can selectively shut off submodule updating, did you do that and forget? `git config --list` and look for submodule update options.

Comment: If you did `git submodule update` update after `git pull`, your submodule repo should have `def` checked out. Or, just do `git pull --recurse-submodules`. I think `git status` saying "HEAD detached at abc" is what's confusing: what it means is "HEAD used to be at `abc`, but it's not anymore". It's very confusing! So I prefer to just do `git status` in the superproject. If all is clean, it means all submodules are checked out at the commit recorded in the currently checked out superproject commit.

Comment: I checked the Git source code, and it seems that if what I say above is what's happening, `git status` in the submodule should say "detached from abc" (in contrast to "detached at abc".