# How to make git bash show branch name in submodules

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, git-submodules

Git bash shows the branch name as

```
 (master)
```

But when using submodules, it now shows the hash and not the name, for example:

```
 ((445c03f...))
```

How can I make it show the name of the branch while inside a submodule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Comment: @Eng_Farghly https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570998/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rule for beginners: Submodules don't use branch names.  Rule for advanced Git users: Submodules don't use branch names *yet*.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9196301)   (See link to glean the meaning of the word *yet* here.)

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570998/1256452) that [phd linked to in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851704/how-to-make-git-bash-show-branch-name-in-submodules#comment119930226_67851704) noted, Git submodules are *normally* in detached-HEAD mode.  What you see—the hash ID of the detached HEAD—when you enter the submodule is reality.  Showing a branch name here might be a beautiful illusion, but beware beautiful illusions: they may cause you to walk along a pretty, yellow brick road that actually simply drops off a cliff.

The general idea here is that it's the *superproject commit* that dictates what should be checked out.  This is, after all, the case with the *superproject's* files: if you `git checkout a123456` in the superproject, you get all the files that go with commit `a123456`.<sup>1</sup>  If that commit requires commit `b789abc` in submodule `sub/mod`, should not `sub/mod` have commit `b789abc` also checked out?<sup>2</sup>

The actual implementation of all of this, in Git, has major rough edges.  It puts me in mind of a shop full of power tools that lack [safety guards](http://www.bu.edu/ehs/ehs-topics/machine-guarding/power-tool-guard-safety/).  The `git submodule update` command *can* make use of branch names, but the ways it does make use of branch names are confusing (sensible in certain contexts, but confusing).  If you want to use submodules, try to treat them as read-only "get this commit from this repository" operations as much as possible, because that's what Git tends to do with them.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, that is, as long as we are not playing clever index and working tree tricks, as seen in [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

<sup>2</sup>And yet, unless you use `--recursive` or set various options, `git checkout` *doesn't* check out `b789abc` automatically: you have to run `git submodule update`.  Setting the recursive option makes this—by *this*  I mean `git checkout` / `git switch`—behave well, but because submodules are so rigid and fragile and messy, I don't really like setting the recursive option.