# Update command in .gitmodules file throws an error

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am new to the submodule feature of git and at the moment I am struggling with the .gitmodules configuration. What I want is to initialize the submodule and checkout to the develop branch and not to the head.

My .gitmodules looks like the following:

```
[submodule "test-submodule"]
    path = test-submodule
    url = https://...
    update = checkout develop
```

When I run

```
git submodule init
```

I get the following error: **fatal: invalid value for submodule.test-submodule.update**

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `submodule.<name>.update` configuration variable [can be](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203) `checkout`, `rebase` or `merge` and nothing else.

Comment: if you can't specify a branch, then what is checkout good for?

Comment: You specify the branch [separately](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#Documentation/gitmodules.txt-submoduleltnamegtbranch)

Comment: I see, I tried it, it checkout to the latest commit of the develop branch. If I go to the submodule folder and call "git branch", then the output tells me "HEAD detached at ...." is the active branch and not the develop branch. Do you have any idea how I can set the develop branch as active?

Comment: "**HEAD detached is the default behavior of** `git submodule update`" See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570998/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+HEAD