# Pulling submodules with different commends brings different results

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a 2 GitHub repos and one of the is included into the other as a submodule. When I call `git pull --recurse-submodules`, I get the version of the submodule, that is no more the current one (not from the last commit, but from one of the older). When I run `git submodule update --recursive --remote`, I get the current version. What is happening here and how do I make the first command to pull the current submodule version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1778247/7976758 "*…submodules are not on a branch. They are … just a pointer to a particular commit…*" I.e., the superproject stores (in every commit) the state (commit ID) of every submodule. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570998/7976758 "*Every commit of a repo is a snapshot/state of your code at that time. The state of submodule at that time has to be deterministic too.*"

Comment: BTW after you did `git submodule update --recursive --remote` you should return to the superproject directory and commit the change in the submodule: `git add <submodule> && git commit -m "Update <submodule>"`

Answer (score 0):

As phd point in comments to the question: "after you did `git submodule update --recursive --remote` you should return to the superproject directory and commit the change in the submodule: `git add <submodule> && git commit -m "Update <submodule>"`"