# How to pull the latest commit of git submodule?

Tags: repository, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have a repo called "**dev_repo**" in which I have added two different repo's (**sub_dev_repo_a **and **sub_dev_repo_b**) as submodules with the following commands

- git submodule add -b **development_branch**<url of **sub_dev_repo_a**>
- git config -f .gitmodules submodule.**sub_dev_repo_a**.update rebase
- git submodule update --remote

Now, if I clone the **dev_repo**and do submodule init in another PC, I can see the submodule is pointing to the latest commit of the **development_branch**of **sub_dev_repo_a**.

Then, I have added some changes to the **development_branch** of **sub_dev_repo_a**- new commit and checked in to the **dev_repo**

When I try to pull it from the another PC with the command "git submodule update --recursive --remote
", it is not getting updated to the new commit ID of submodule (**development_branch**) .

What is the correct way to pull the latest changes of submodule every time when a new commit is done to the repo/branch it is pointing to?

Tried following the answers from here - [Why is my Git Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Still couldn't get it right.