# Why does git submodule keep updating in detached head mode?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add a submodule to my git repo, I deleted the sub module repo and recreated it, I then readded it to my repo but whenever I update the submodule it pulls some specific commit which doesn't exist in the current git history.

1. Initially I forked the original glfw/glfw repo
2. I ran `git submodule add git@github.com:me/glfw.git Modules/GLFW`
3. I then realized that the tutorial author had made some changes to his fork of glfw so removed the sub module `git rm Modules/GLFW`, I deleted my fork repo, I then forked his repo with the same name as my previous one.
4. I then added the submodule again `git submodule add git@github.com:me/glfw.git Modules/GLFW`

Now every time I fetch or update the submodule it seems to pull it back in detached head mode, and the contents of the repo are the same as the old fork.

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'Modules/GLFW' (git@github.com:me/glfw.git) registered for path 'Modules/GLFW'
Cloning into '~/Development/Personal/MyProject/Modules/GLFW'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1811, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (530/530), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 1811 (delta 510), reused 522 (delta 510), pack-reused 1281
Receiving objects: 100% (1811/1811), 1.20 MiB | 471.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1311/1311), completed with 108 local objects.
From github.com:me/glfw
 * branch              6f1ddf51a130f2dee6ade5fa4d8217e4071124e8 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'Modules/GLFW': checked out '6f1ddf51a130f2dee6ade5fa4d8217e4071124e8'
```

In github I can see a reference to the submodule @6f1ddf51a130f2dee6ade5fa4d8217e4071124e8, but when I go to the fork repo it claims there is no branch or commit that matches it.

I've tried explicitly setting the branch for the submodule but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/6f1ddf51a130f2dee6ade5fa4d8217e4071124e8) the commit `6f1ddf51a130f2dee6ade5fa4d8217e4071124e8`.  Currently it's the head (tip) of branch `master`. If you question is why the submodule is checked out at the commit and not `master` branch — because that how submodules work: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570998/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+HEAD

Comment: But that's not the head of master in v2 of my fork?  It's a commit from v1 of it.  If I look at master HEAD of my fork in github the root has a premake file which doesn't exist on my local machine/at that commit.

Comment: I think the issue is that I think I didn't properly clean up the submodule add from v1, so the question is how do I properly remove a submodule? or how do I amend the updated one

Comment: Remove a submodule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+remove

Comment: Update a submodule: `git submdule update --remote path/to/submodule && git commit path/to/submodule`