# git checkout version including submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

How can I checkout a git repo including its submodules?

e.g. I have a repo A, with a submodule B, the commit history is as follows:

- f7fe0a4 A, bcbaec2 B (latest)
- 206c8dd A, bcbaec2 B
- 0fd667c A, bcbaec2 B
- 0ec21a1 A, e79fea0 B (older version)

I want to temporarily go back to an older version of A, so I stashed local changes in A and B, then `git checkout 0ec21a1`

But Im still on the latest version of the submodule. I expected the submodule to updated according to the parent version. My understanding from this question, [submodule tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag) is that git does not manage submodules when you checkout the parent, is this correct?

My real commit history is more complicated and there are several submodules. Is there a way to determine what version of submodule B was used in commit xxx of A? I can get approximate versions by comparing the git logs but it's rather painful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is git submodule update not automatic on git checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899792/why-is-git-submodule-update-not-automatic-on-git-checkout)

Comment: Yes, that response answers this question. So what I was missing was 'git submodule update'

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout 0ec21a1 --recurse-submodules` will update the content of submodule B (if it's already initialized) according to the commit which is stored in parent project A (in this case will checkout `e79fea0`)

Comment: Thanks, that should work, unfortunately Im stuck with v2.8 of git this feature was added in v2.13. In any case adding git submodule update after the checkout works